# Is it possible to convert a Device Dependant Bitmap into a normal, displayable bitmap?

Tags: windows, winapi, bitmap

I have recently came across a file, it is labelled as a proprietary file extension, however, using trid they are recognised as Device Dependant Bitmaps. They are textures for a virtual world map of some sorts. Is it possible to convert these files into a normal bitmap file that can be edited in image editing software? Thanks.

Comment: Yes an no. It is a bitmap after all, so you can immediately edit it in any graphics application that supports this image format (like MS Paint). As for displaying the image, that may not be accurately possible. Part of the color information isn't stored in the file but rather implied by the display device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have attempted to open the file format in paintdotnet and paint, and both don't recognise it. Would I have to change the file extension to allow this to work?

Comment: Paint.NET is just some hobby project. It's not something you should regard as a reference implementation for file formats. MS Paint, on the other hand, is a very comprehensive and solid implementation of the BMP file format. If MS Paint won't load your image, it's probably some obscure file format (not BMP). Seeing that BMPs are in fact device-independent by nature, I'm not sure what image format you have. Can you post a hexdump of the image file?

Comment: Here are the first few lines:

Comment: https://shrib.com/#AmericanBison832DWWO

Comment: Please add that to the question instead of a comment. The file format doesn't look familiar, but it's certainly not a BMP. Could it be from [this project](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/)?

Comment: It's from a flight simulator game actually, looking into making mods for the maps that are already there. (Re-texture etc)